# CallKit with TokBox detects speaker on after receiving the call

Tags: ios, swift, opentok, tokbox, callkit

After Receiving the call, the speaker in the calling screen automatically become active. Also by taping it, is hasn't deactivated while in call, if voice session activated.

Does any one face similar issue and solved the same ?

Any help will be appreciable

Thanks.

Comment: Any solution for this issue? or still facing this?